# Does convergence in probability of A_n to 0 result $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(A_n\geq0)=1$?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus

> Assume $A_1, A_2, \cdots$ is an i.i.d sequence of random variables with finite mean and variance. If $A_n$ converges to zero in probability, i.e., $\forall \gamma>0: \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}\left(|A_n|\geq\gamma\right)=0$, is the following true?
>   $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}\left(A_n\geq0\right)=1$$

I think the answer is no and there should be counter examples. Can you help find that?

Comment: Since the $A_n$ are identically distributed, $P(|A_n|≥\gamma)$ is the same for all $n$.

Comment: Seems like we have $A_n=0$ for all $n$ then?

Comment: @manofbear almost surely, yes.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: As others pointed out below, my example doesn't meet the iid condition. Sorry about that oversight - looking for another counterexample or a proof.

How about $A_n=-\frac{1}{n}$? Then for any $\gamma>0$, $|A_n|<\gamma$ eventually, and $A_n<0$ for all $n$.

Comment: what is the distribution of $A_n$?

Comment: The $A_n$ are meant to be identically distributed.

Comment: Whoops. Good point guys, my answer doesn't work. Missed the iid part

Comment: Since the question does not make sense for $\{A_i\}$ iid, this is a good answer for the natural fix of assuming $\{A_i\}$ are mutually independent (not necessarily iid) but converging to 0 in probability.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, iid means that $\mathbb{P}\left(|A_n|\geq\gamma\right)$ is independent of $n$. Therefore
$$
\forall \gamma>0: \lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}\left(|A_n|\geq\gamma\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(|A_1|\geq\gamma\right)
$$
and this is $=0$ if
$$
\forall \gamma>0: \mathbb{P}\left(|A_1|\geq\gamma\right)=0.
$$
This only works for the degenerate distribution with $\mathbb{P}\left(A_1=0\right)=1$.

In that case,
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}\left(A_n\geq0\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(A_1\geq0\right)=1.
$$